# Getting Instagram redirect from Python Requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib, instagram-api, python-webbrowser

In performing oauth2 for Instagram there is a redirect call of the form:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=<XXX>&redirect_uri=<YYY>&response_type=code&scope=basic+likes+comments
```

When coded with **Requests**:

```
s = requests.Session()

###Create URL call with query parameters
user_AuthRequest_Instagram = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=' + Client_ID + '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_URL + '&response_type=code&scope=basic+likes+comments'

###Get the result of this URL
r = s.get(user_AuthRequest_Instagram, allow_redirects=True, timeout=120)

###Checking results
print(r.status_code, r.url, r.cookies, r.text)
```

where *Client_ID* and *redirect_URL* are appropriate values. This does produce a 200 HTTP status_code value, but the redirect is never called as a result of post. The same approach with **urllib** produces the same result; it never calls the redirect even though it returns a 200 status_code.

Taking the exact same URL command and dropping it in Chrome is successful, with the redirect fully working from Instagram. I even tested this with success using **WebBrower**:

```
import webbrowser
b = webbrowser.get('chrome')
webbrowser.open(user_AuthRequest_Instagram)
```

So why does **Requests** approach never work for this URL redirect case?

Comment: were you able to succeed in this am having the same issue but unable to find the solution.

Comment: Yes, I am successful using the approach given below in Answer #1. Make sure your browser can execute the Javascript  and you are on a computer with the Instagram account open.

Answer (score 0):

The approach to solving this issue for the first step of the Instagram authentication process to get an oauth2 token for the Server-side (explicit) case requires the user to to send the initial post from their browser. This requirement explains the problem I had with **Requests**, since these are outside of the browser environment while webbrowser works.

I found the best solution to automate this user authentication step is to use something like **Bottles** and create a button with the action being the appropriate Instagram call. This looks like:

```
    from bottle import Bottle, run, route, request, response, template, redirect

    @app.route('/BestTag_Auth')
    def user_Auth_Instagram():
       #Initializations
       Scope_Lst = 'basic+likes+comments+public_content'

       #Create link for user to authorize BestTag
       user_AuthRequest_Instagram = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=' + <Client_ID> + '&redirect_uri=' + <redirect_URL> + '&response_type=code&scope=' + Scope_Lst   

       #Send Web page with button to user
       location_URL = "location.href='" + user_AuthRequest_Instagram + "';" 
       auth_Button = '<input type="button" onclick="' + location_URL + '" value="Get authorization" />'

       return auth_Button
```

You can then use a similar approach to catch the Instagram redirect and finish getting the token.

Comment: Hi I tried this approach but m still not getting the code or accesstoken.
rather my output is giving me. <input type="button" onclick="location.href='https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/users/auth/instagram/callback&response_type=code&scope=basic+likes+comments+public_content';" value="Get authorization" />

Could you please let me know if am missing anything.

Comment: It appears your browser is not letting the Javascript for the button execute. Make sure that Javascript is enabled on the browser your are using. I am using the chrome browser.

Comment: am using chrome browser as well.
I will give a try once again.